# c# Ссылка на объект

Tags: c#, исключения

Недавно начал кодить на c# и наткнулся на одно "магическое" исключение `System.NullReferenceException: "В экземпляре объекта не задана ссылка на объект."` 
Пытался найти в гугле о ссылках и вроде нашёл, но так ничего не понял.

Надеюсь вы мне поможете разобраться с этой чёрной магией

Вот код (обновлено):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleTest
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string[] add;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("> ");
                var str = Console.ReadLine();


                Console.WriteLine();
                var arg = str.Split(' ');
                if (arg[0] == "set")
                {
                    add[Int32.Parse(arg[1])] = arg[2];
                    Console.WriteLine("Added {0} => {1}", arg[1], arg[2]);
                }
                else if (arg[0] == "get")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Returned {0} => {1}", arg[1], add[Int32.Parse(arg[1])]);
                }


            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Слишком много правок XD)

Выдаёт ошибку на строке `add[Int32.Parse(arg[1])] = arg[2];`

### Чуть подробнее

После запуска я пишу `add 5 test` потом <kbd>Enter</kbd> и вылезает ошибка.

По замыслу должно сделаться это (естественно ошибка не была в планах): `add[5] = "test";`

Строкой `add[Int32.Parse(arg[1])] = arg[2];` я пытаюсь добавить в массив `add` значение `arg[2]` с индексом `arg[1]` (+ преобразование строки в число).

Массив `arg` это полученная строка через `Console.ReadLine()` и разбитая с помощью `.Split(' ')`

Массив `add` объявлен: `public static string[] add;`

Я путался добавлять пустые элементы так:

```
whlie(add[Int32.Parse(arg[1])] == null) { add.Add(""); }
```

но это не помогло.

### Суть проблемы

Я не знаю конечного кол-ва мест для содержимого, т.к. это id сессии, номер которой может быть непредсказуемым.

### И так, господа

Сегодня я вам всем изрядно напряг мозги, я благодарю вас за терпение.

Спасибо всем за советы, но до решения я дошёл сам

#### Т.к. я не нашёл кнопку ответа, то ответ тут

```
public static void _add(int key, string val) {
    if (key >= add.Length) { Array.Resize(ref add, key + 1); }
    add[key] = val;
    foreach (var item in add)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Я добавил эту функцию и когда надо записать что-то в массив `add` я писал `_add(index, value)` и всё стало хорошо.

Теперь главное чтобы `mono` смог скомпилировать сие чудо (`mcs` на linux)

Comment: Не совсем. Там отношения между классами а у меня функция не видит переменную, которая лежит в этом же классе

Comment: отсутствует значение

Comment: Может, Вы добавите объяснение того, что этот код пытается делать, и с какими параметрами Вы его вызываете? А вообще-то, `add` нигде не назначается и остаётся с дефолтным значением `null`.

Comment: что ты хочешь этим сделать ? `add[Int32.Parse(arg[1])] = arg[2];`

Comment: Здесь вы `public static string[] add;` объявляете переменную, но не создаете массив, а здесь `add[Int32.Parse(arg[1])] = arg[2];` пытаетесь писать в массив, но он же еще не был создан?!

Comment: @Дмитрий Массив `add` **НЕ** СОЗДАН: `public static string[] add;`, а **объявлен** - "почувствуйте разницу".

Comment: @Igor Не чувствую. Что тогда есть **создан**?

Comment: @Дмитрий `add = new string[123];` - создает массив строк, в котором есть места для 123-х элементов. А `public static string[] add;` - говорит, что в классе есть статическое поле, которое может указывать на массив строк, какой-нубудь длины, а может никуда не указывать (`null`) - что является его начальным состоянием.

Comment: @Igor А что делать если я не знаю длину массив (сколько мест надо) ибо она динамичная. Я нашёл в документации `.Resize` но проблема в том, что это только для .NET 4.5

Comment: @Дмитрий Надо создавать массив в тот момент, когда его длина станет известна. Но я так и не понял, зачем Вам этот массив. Может быть вместо него подойдет `Dictionary<string, string>`.

Comment: @Igor Этот массив просто для теста записи. Но т.к. я не хотел засорять тестами код с сокетами (сервер), то запихнул тест сюда (это давно забытое мной консольное приложение с системой "функций"). | Смысл был таков, что один юзер записывает в серверную переменную что-то с id своей сессии, а другой получает по id сессии это содержимое. А за совет спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: @Дмитрий естественно, при выполнении условия `if (key >= add.Length)` Вы не присваиваете значение.

Comment: Господа,а как на свой ответить? XD

Comment: @Дмитрий на этот вопрос Вы в данный момент не можете ответить, потому что он закрыт, как дубликат

Answer (score 1):

```
else if (arg[0] == "add" && arg.Count() >= 2)
{
    switch (arg[1])
    {
        case ("test"):
            add = new string[] { "test_val" };
            //add[0] = "test_val";
            Console.WriteLine("Added test_key => test_val");
            break;
        default:
            //здесь не понятно что ты хочешь сделать?
            if (arg.Count() >= 3 && Int32.Parse(arg[1])>=0)
            {
                var a = Int32.Parse(arg[1]);
                add = new string[a + 1];
                add[Int32.Parse(arg[1])] = arg[2];
                Console.WriteLine("Added {0} => {1}", arg[1], arg[2]);
            }arg[2]);
            break;
    }
}
else if (arg[0] == "get" && arg.Count() >= 2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Returned {0} => {1}", arg[1], add[Int32.Parse(arg[1])]);
}
```

Comment: `//здесь не понятно что ты хочешь сделать?
            if (arg.Count() >= 3 && Int32.Parse(arg[1])>=0)` это где у меня в коде?

Comment: add[Int32.Parse(arg[1])] = arg[2];